# How can I terminate a thread in Python3 after a specified timeout?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm invoking `git` as a shell command, and want to timeout after `X` amount of seconds and terminate the operation.

I've considered `multiprocessing.Process`, since it has `join()` with a timeout and `terminate()`. However, I'd prefer using a thread for a couple of reasons:

- It's more lightweight
- The code invoking the `git` is already running in a `multiprocessing.Process` with `daemon=True`, and so cannot spawn child processes itself (except if I change `daemon=False`, but then the parent of the spawning process won't its child).

How can I run the `git` command in a thread using a timeout, and terminate the thread if
the timeout has elapsed?